# Add angular app in already existing app and transfer data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am trying to add angular app in already existing jquery app.
Suppose i have a simple button in html.
I am trying to load angular app and run controller code on button click. I load the angular app mannually using `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])` . and also i am trying to pass some data from jquery to angular app. Can it be possible??

Have a look-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>jA</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myButton" value="25">Hello world</button>
</body>
<script>

    angular.module('myApp', [])     // I defined the angular app.
            .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                console.log('Hello world');  // This should run on button click.
            }]);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myButton").click(function(){
            var some_value = '25';   //value i am trying to pass to angular app to use in angular app.
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']); //load angular app

        });

    });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you can direct access some_value in controller

Comment: i am not sure about that, but how to run controller code on button click.

Comment: Try create a service or const with the given value for example angular.module('myApp').constant('buttonValue', $(this).val()), and inject the constant in the controller

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` and `AngularJS` don't "talk" to each other directly, but Angular does "see" any other native javascript you have, so lets say - if you define a global variable and change it via `jQuery` when `AnuglarjJS` will access it - it can read and use the value.

Giving your example - who's using/calling `MyController` ?

check out the fiddle I've created for you as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/b29rng12/2/

```
<div id="myAngularApp">

  <button id="myButton" value="25"> click to bootstrap</button>
  <p ng-controller='MyController'>
    this section will be bind to the controller. {{ test }} and the value is {{ some_jquery_value }}
  </p>
</div>

<script>
    var some_value = '25';   //value i am trying to pass to angular app to use in angular app.

    angular.module('myApp', [])     // I defined the angular app.
            .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                console.log('Hello world');  // This should run on button click.
                $scope.test = "ricky";
                $scope.some_jquery_value = some_value;   // This is your predefined variable
            }]);


  $("#myButton").click(function(){  
    some_value = 30;
    angular.bootstrap($("#myAngularApp"), ['myApp']); //load angular app
  });

</script>
```

So just to explain - the app starts when its not bootstrapped, this is why you'll see `{{ }}` instead of values.

After you'll click the button ( as in your example ) - the app is bootstrapped - it still doesn't mean that this code will use the specific `controller` that you had in mind ( angular module can have 100 controllers - so who will use what ?! )
So I've defined `<p ng-controller='MyController'>` - is what binds the controller after the `app` has been bootstrapped.

I hope it helps ....